# tensorflow custom loss that are not in the form of sum of single sample errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was working through [here](http://stackabuse.com/tensorflow-neural-network-tutorial/). I am currently modifying the loss. Looking at,

```
    deltas=tf.square(y_est-y)
    loss=tf.reduce_sum(deltas)
```

I am understanding this to be calculating the squared difference between the output and the true label. Then the loss is the sum of these squares. So, writing the squared single sample error as `S_i` for sample `i`, things are simple for the case when the batch loss is just `\sum_{i} f(S_i)`,
where summation goes through the all samples. But what if you cannot write the loss in this form? That is, the batch loss for the whole data is `f({S_i})` for some general `f` with `i` going over all the samples. That is, the loss for the whole data cannot be calculated as some simple linear combination of the losses for the constituent samples. How do you code this in tensorflow? Thank you.

Below is more details on `f`. The outputs of the neural network are `u_i` where `i` goes from 1 to n. n is the number of samples we have. My error is something like

```
sum_{i from 1 to n} C_i log{sum_{k from 1 to n} I_{ik} exp{-d(u_i,u_k)} }
```

`C_i` is number of nodes connected to node `i`, which I already have and is a constant. `I_{ik}` is 1 if node `i` and node `k` is not connected.

Thanks for the code. maybe my question has not been worded correctly. I am not really looking for the code for the loss. This I can do myself. If you look at,

```
deltas=tf.square(y_est-y)
loss=tf.reduce_sum(deltas)
```

deltas, are they (1,3)? A bit above it reads

```
# Placeholders for input and output data
X = tf.placeholder(shape=(120, 4), dtype=tf.float64, name='X')
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(120, 3), dtype=tf.float64, name='y')

# Variables for two group of weights between the three layers of the network
W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(4, hidden_nodes), dtype=tf.float64)
W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(hidden_nodes, 3), dtype=tf.float64)

# Create the neural net graph
A1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W1))
y_est = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(A1, W2))
```

I think it is (1,3). They use (1,3) `y_est` and `y`. I want to know the specific tensorflow syntax for working with (m,3) `y_est` and `y` for any given m.

Comment: You could define/code the f function and do loss = f(s_i)?

Comment: @UmangGupta if the i in f(s_i) is on a singleton, I can define/code the f function. I don't know how to do it when the i runs through the whole batch B.

Comment: I can explain it with code if you give more details about the function f. I think I don't understand the problem. You can access each element in batch by indices? right?

Comment: @UmangGupta I just edited my question. After a second look, I think I need the output for all samples. In fact I'm not too sure how I should be accessing the outputs by indices (if what you meant by element was the outputs of the neural network).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong with syntaxes ... but this should give you a general idea. Also, you can optimize it further by vectorization. I have simply put your loss function as it is.
N is the batch size.

```
def f(C, I, U, N):
    loss = 0
    for i in range(N):
         sum_ = 0
         for k in range(N):
              sum_ += I[i,k] * tf.exp(d(u[i]-u[k])
         loss += C[i]*tf.log(sum)
    return loss    
loss = f(C,I,U, batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. maybe my question has not been worded correctly. I am not really looking for the code for the loss. This I can do myself.

Comment: @ztyh I added the coded thinking it will help you understand. 
1. How to define any general loss over samples?
2. How to index samples in batches?

Comment: Thanks, but your response is not really in line with the code in question. `y_est` is (1,3), but your `U` is already (m,3). Also there is no confirmation that tensorflow can indeed work with custom loss calculated on a (m,3) `U` instead of a (1,3) `y_est`. Your response really doesn't have anything to do with tensorflow apart from some use of tensorflow functions.

Comment: @ztyh I think there is some misunderstanding on my part and I am here to help. 
U is (m,3), I am assuming 3 is batch size, usually batch size is written first so let it be (3,m). But I was assuming the function `d` is a distance function and hence scalar? no? The loss has to be scalar to be able to optimize, otherwise argmin (or argmax) won't make sense.

Comment: `Your response really doesn't have anything to do with tensorflow apart from some use of tensorflow functions.`
Well um! if you are using tensorflow you can indeed define loss this way. I mean it doesn't need to have something special with tensorflow and that is why I was trying to respond in comments and not as answer.

Comment: In hindsight, I could treat the whole sample as one sample, that is, my input is (1,120,4), output is something like (1,120,d). This would be our `y_est` and I can calculate a loss of it against the (1,120,d) `y`. Maybe you were intending to say this.

Comment: @ztyh Yes I think you got it, but I am not sure my intention was that. All I was trying to say that the batch_size is another dimension and your can iterate over it and calculate any `f`

Comment: you can only iterate over the batch if the loss is of a simple form, like a sum of errors for constituent samples, as I mentioned in the question. If the loss is complicated, like in my case, you cannot iterate. That is why I need to feed in the whole data as a single sample.

Comment: @ztyh I am not sure what case you are talking about, my answer shows the loss you talked about in the problem previously. 
You can iterate over `m` dimension too (if you are looking for that). But finally loss has to be a scalar to be optimized for.

Comment: can you iterate over the `m` dimensions even if your input is (1,4) and your output `y_est` is (1,d)? I don't think so. I am just not convinced that this is true. I think it is iterable over `m` only if your input is (1,m,4) and your out put is (m,d) in the neural network.

Comment: @ztyh `can you iterate over the m dimensions even if your input is (1,4) and your output y_est is (1,d)?`It is obvious you can't. If there is no variable with `m` dimesion to iterate on, you can't iterate.

I don't think I understand your use case. My apologies for that. I will end this discussion with this statement: `if you can write loss as f defined above in the answer, you can use that loss with tensorflow`  
Note: You representations are somewhat confusing. Usually, I use batch size as the first index. This might be helpful when asking questions.